# Worklight v6.2 - Android Cordova Plug-in

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-plugins

Has anyone tried the "Android - Adding native functionality to Hybrid Application using Apache Cordova plug-in" feature in v6.2 ?

I'm trying to use a 3rd party library on the client side and wanted to understand where to put the plug-in java class in the project. The documentation shows a java package (src) structure whereas the best I can find is normal folders in the android native folder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you see these as "regular" folders is likely because you are look at the Worklight project rather than the generated Android project.

Worklight project\apps\your_app\android\native\ ... will look as folders because they are indeed just folders.
Once you build your Worklight application (containing an Android environment), an Android project will be generated. In it, you will see the folders as packages, etc.

A Worklight project and application structure is explained in earlier training modules:

- [Creating your first Hybrid Worklight application](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/02_01_Creating_your_first_Hybrid_Worklight_application.pdf)
- [Previewing your application on Android](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/02_07_Previewing_your_application_on_Android.pdf)

So, you should place your Java Class file in Worklight project\apps\your_app\android\native\src\com\package_name\ ...

---

Note about Cordova plug-ins in Worklight: depending on the plug-in this may not be possible to use as some plug-ins require using the Cordova plugman, which is not yet supported in Worklight.

Comment: Hi Idan, I tried adding my Plugin java class to the android/native/src ..under a package com.etc.etc. I also added a plugin jar to the android/native/libs folder. What I find is that everytime I generate the android build, its deleting all my classes in the android build AND my worklight project paths also.

Comment: Correct. In this case you will need to place your files in the android\nativeResources folder instead; mirror the file structure and on build it will copy it to the native folder.